# PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] empty

Tags: php, apache

Somehow `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` returns an empty string, i have the same code (as part of a script) running on multiple servers and it works everywhere else, they are all the same setup.

The weird thing is, when I restart apache and load the page, it works exactly once, if I reload the site + all the times after that, it's empty. I've had other people try, same result, empty.

someone suggested it was something with IPv6 configuration, I have now completely disabled IPv6 but the problem persists.

Comment: Using Apache? Any caching ?

Comment: Yes apache, no caching.

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is used by Apache as module and not CGI ?

Comment: Yes PHP is loaded as a module. It's weird in phpinfo it works, if I upload a new file which has only <?php echo $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; ?> in it, it works, once. If I upload another file with same content, on this file it will work again, once!

Comment: Is apache running behind a proxy?

Answer (score 3):

if you're behind a proxy server, you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` or `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` instead of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.
this will depends on how your proxy is configured.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible for REMOTE_ADDR to be empty.
so if you want you can use this code that I use to get the ip based on HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

```
<?php
    if(! empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
else{
    $ip = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? '' : $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
```

I'm checking **REMOTE_ADDR** first as it is more reliable and sometimes **HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR** can be spoofed by users

Comment: I think it is better to use `isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])` rather than `empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])`

Comment: you know the difference with isset and empty right? When I looked before on my server's log. I've encountered some browser still sending http_x_forward_for but it's blank. so I think its empty() is needed

Comment: actually it is best to use both... because it is possible that clients might not using proxy so they do not have the `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` variable set....so by just check empty will lead to some issues when php parse it....imho..

Comment: Andrew, empty is using both isset() and checking if not blank string. it won't throw php warning too. Maybe you're thinking of it the other way around...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php  Cheers mate

Comment: thanks for ur reminder..I always thought empty will only check for ..empty as the function name stated...:) to me its more readable `isset + empty` :)

Answer (score 1):

I had code on a new VM that looked like this. It is being called from a javascript file:

```
<?php
$hostip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
?>
var myip = "<?=$hostip ?>";
```

Worked on the old server of course and I was scratching my head for a while thinking there was something wrong with Apache..Was there a module missing? Some obscure Apache setting I can't find?.  I thought Apache wasn't sending on the Server variables. That was until I tried the plain ol' fashioned way and it worked:

```
echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

Turned out I had to edit php.ini and set **short_open_tag** to **On**. Facepalm - the shortcut php tags weren't working. Hopefully that will help save someone else a head of time :)