# using the IP address for locating my users

Tags: php

For some reason this code only works when I change the `$ip` to my current IP address. Is there something that I need to do to the PHP.ini file for this code to work dynamically?

Even when I download the code from the internet it does not display, and it has nothing to do with the API I am using, I even tried [PHP $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005012/php-serverremote-addr-empty) that code wont work.i think there is a setting i need to do. i am using MAMP, and a MAC. this is what its displaying "::1"

```
<?php
// Get User IP
if(! empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
else{
    $ip = empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? '' : $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}
//Send the API request with user Ip
$ipinfoAPI = "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json";
//get the APi requeted data
$load = file_get_contents($ipinfoAPI);
//Convert it to the readable format
$return = json_decode($load);
echo $return->ip;
?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting and/or check your error logs

Comment: After you create `$ipinfoAPI = "http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}/json";`, you should `echo` this value out on the page, copy and paste it in your browser and see if it's working. That may be pretty telling, especially if it's working with a value you input manually.

Comment: What I'm assuming is happening is `empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` is true for some reason, and `empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])` is also true, making `$ip = '';`

Comment: Why don't you use `CURL` instead of `file_get_contents()`

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is probably returning `::1` (IPv6) since you're using a local development solution.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar What's wrong with `file_get_contents()`? In my experience, it's much easier to use than CURL

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton As a developer we need to follow some standards. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488425/php-ini-file-get-contents-external-url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a MAMP return ::1 as IP on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699454/should-a-mamp-return-1-as-ip-on-localhost)

Comment: In your case you will only get loopback IP. You can't locate with that.

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar Thanks for the link.

Comment: @freddyrobinson i tried using Listen 127.0.0.1:8080, it shows 127.0.0.1 not my IP address

Comment: @BanujanBalendrakumar PHP's built-in curl functions are, frankly, awful; for a simple request like this I would probably jump straight from `file_get_contents` to installing [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/), rather than bothering to write the boilerplate needed for curl to give me something meaningful.

Comment: Try dumping the contents of `$_SERVER` - what are the values of REMOTE_ADDR and HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in that array?